# How can this closed database be opened?

Tags: python, sqlite, web-crawler, python-records

This is the code that I am running:

```
import requests 
import records 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from urllib.parse import urljoin 
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

db = records.Database('sqlite:///crawler_database.db')

db.query('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS links (
            url text PRIMARY KEY,            
            created_at datetime,            
            visited_at datetime NULL)''') 
db.query('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS numbers (url text, number integer,            
            PRIMARY KEY (url, number))''')

def store_link(url):    
    try:        
        db.query('''INSERT INTO links (url, created_at)                    
                    VALUES (:url, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)''', url=url)

    except IntegrityError as ie:       
        # This link already exists, do nothing        
        pass

def store_number(url, number):    
    try:        
        db.query('''INSERT INTO numbers (url, number)                    
            VALUES (:url, :number)''', url=url, number=number)    
    except IntegrityError as ie:        
        # This number already exists, do nothing        
        pass

def mark_visited(url):    
    db.query('''UPDATE links SET visited_at=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP                
                WHERE url=:url''', url=url)

def get_random_unvisited_link():    
    link = db.query('''SELECT * FROM links                       
                       WHERE visited_at IS NULL                        
                       ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1''').first()    
    return None if link is None else link.url

def visit(url):    
    html = requests.get(url).text    
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')    
    new_links = []    
    for td in html_soup.find_all("td"):        
    store_number(url, int(td.text.strip()))    
    for link in html_soup.find_all("a"):        
        link_url = link.get('href')        
        if link_url is None:            
            continue        
        full_url = urljoin(url, link_url)        
        new_links.append(full_url)    
    return new_links

store_link('http://www.webscrapingfordatascience.com/crawler/') 
url_to_visit = get_random_unvisited_link() 
while url_to_visit is not None:    
    print('Now visiting:', url_to_visit)    
    new_links = visit(url_to_visit)    
    print(len(new_links), 'new link(s) found')    
    for link in new_links:        
        store_link(link)    
    mark_visited(url_to_visit)    
    url_to_visit = get_random_unvisited_link()
```

This is my error:

> ProgrammingError: (sqlite3.ProgrammingError) Cannot operate on a closed database.

The callback error says points me to this line, `url_to_visit = get_random_unvisited_link()`.

I cannot understand why it is closed or what is going on. Anyone who would like to help me solve this?

This is the full traceback:

```
ERROR:sqlalchemy.pool.impl.NullPool:Error closing cursor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 1324, in fetchone
    row = self._fetchone_impl()
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 1204, in _fetchone_impl
    return self.cursor.fetchone()
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1339, in _safe_close_cursor
    cursor.close()
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database.
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue arises when calling `.first()` on the `RecordCollection` returned in `get_random_unvisited_link`. I'm not certain, but I suspect that there is a bug in the `records` package whereby the return of the rows as a generator `RecordCollection` malfunctions since the `cursor` is being deleted. I believe this is the same issue as reported on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/kennethreitz-archive/records/pull/190).

To elaborate, modifying your `get_random_unvisited_link` to:

```
def get_random_unvisited_link():                                                
    link = db.query('''SELECT * FROM links                                      
                       WHERE visited_at IS NULL                                 
                       ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1''')                            
    print(link)                                                                 
    for row in link:                                                            
        print(row)
```

outputs:

```
<RecordCollection size=0 pending=True>
Error closing cursor
...Traceback from question...
```

which indicates that the `RecordCollection` still has pending items, but trying to access these items results in the message

> Error closing cursor

followed by the traceback you saw.

There is a workaround for this, using the `fetchall` parameter to `query`:

```
def get_random_unvisited_link():                                                
    rows = db.query('''SELECT * FROM links                                      
                       WHERE visited_at IS NULL                                 
                       ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1''', fetchall=True)             
    print(rows)                                                                 
    link = rows.first()                                                         
    print(link)                                                                 
    return None if link is None else link.url
```

Print output:

```
<RecordCollection size=1 pending=False>
<Record {"url": "http://www.webscrapingfordatascience.com/crawler/", "created_at": "2020-04-14 06:57:45", "visited_at": null}>
```

Now, you can see that we have loaded the results of the query into the `RecordCollection`, since its `size` is `1` and the `pending` flag is `False`.

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot. Basically, the problem is with the calling of the RawCollection.

Comment: Sorry, I should have written `RecordCollection` in all cases. Yes, it tries to lazy-return the records from the database, but the connection is closed before you try to retrieve the results.

Comment: If this has solved your problem (and explained the cause), I would be grateful if you would consider accepting the answer. This will help future readers to find the solution.

Comment: I will always consider accepting future answers. This will be a big help for future readers.